# Groovy SQL: Shall I manually close the Mysql connection

Tags: mysql, grails, groovy

I have a grails service that calls stored procedures using Groovy SQL.
I am using `dataSource` for initializing the connection. 
My question is: Do I need to manually close the connection or will it be handled by Groovy or GORM (since I am using `def dataSource`)?

Here is how my service is structured.

```
class MyService {

    static transactional = Boolean.FALSE

    private static final String STATEMENT_ONE_SQL = "{ call sp_One(?) }"

    private static final String STATEMENT_TWO_SQL = "{ call sp_Two(?,?) }"

    def dataSource

    Sql sql

    @PostConstruct
    def initSql() {
       sql = new Sql(dataSource)
    }

    List<GroovyRowResult> callSpOne(Integer id) {
        List<GroovyRowResult> results = sql.rows(STATEMENT_ONE_SQL, [id])
        return results
    }

    List<GroovyRowResult> callSpTwo(Integer id, String name) {
         List<GroovyRowResult> results = sql.rows(STATEMENT_TWO_SQL, [id, name])
         return results
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Basing on official [docs](http://docs.groovy-lang.org/latest/html/api/groovy/sql/Sql.html)

> Finally, we should clean up:

```
sql.close()
```

> If we are using a DataSource and we haven't enabled statement caching, then strictly speaking the final close() method isn't required - as all connection handling is performed transparently on our behalf; however, it doesn't hurt to have it there as it will return silently in that case.
>
> If instead of newInstance you use withInstance, then close() will be called automatically for you.

Comment: Am I suppose to use `sql.close()` after every call or when?

Comment: Nope, only if you're opening new connection during every request but in your case I'd rather use `sql.close()` in `@PreDestroy`.